# Добавить класс при клике по ссылке

Tags: javascript

```js
let active = document.querySelectorAll("a");

 active.forEach(function (entry) {
  entry.addEventListener("click", btnSelect);
 
  function btnSelect() {
   entry.classList.contains('selected')
   entry.classList.remove('selected')
   this.classList.add('selected');
  };
 });
```

```css
.selected {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
 <a>Link 1</a>
 <a>Link 2</a>
 <a>Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Не получается удалять классы при клике по другому элементу. Подскажите, что не так делаю?

Comment: вы удаляете и добавляете класс у текущей кликнутой кнопки. а удалять судя по всему хотите у всех, а не у текущей.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const links = document.querySelector('.links');

links.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  const target = e.target;

  [...links.children].forEach(child => child.classList.remove('selected'));

  target.classList.add('selected');
});
```

```css
.selected {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link 1</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link 2</a>
  <a href="javascript:void(0);">Link 3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const wrapObj = document.querySelector('.links');
wrapObj.onclick = function(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < wrapObj.children.length; i++) {
    wrapObj.children[i].classList.remove('selected');
  }
  e.target.classList.add('selected');
}
```

```css
.selected {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

```html
<div class="links">
  <a href="#">Link 1</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
  <a href="#">Link 2</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Помимо ссылок, класс .select добавляется и к .links - https://jsfiddle.net/pn018jy7/13/